# Does Process.StartInfo.FileName accept long file names?

Tags: c#

Looks like it's not.

If I convert the file name to its short value, then Process.Start() works.

```
Process runScripts = new Process();
runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\long file path\run.cmd";
runScripts.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
runScripts.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
runScripts.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
runScripts.Start();
```

The above code fails. But...

```
Process runScripts = new Process();
runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\short\file\path\run.cmd";
runScripts.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
runScripts.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
runScripts.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
runScripts.Start();
```

succeeds.

I managed to get around this by converting the long path name to a short path name.
But I am a bit surprised to find this.
Any reasons or background info on this?

Thanks.

**Update 1**
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you running this on?

Comment: Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727

Comment: That's outdated. You should upgrade.

Comment: Upgrade to solve a dev problem? NO. Not if you want your code to run for other .NET 2.0 users. Upgrade to use the latest? Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reproduce your problem, I used the following program:

```
// file test.cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Test
{
    public static int Main()
    {
        string error;
        try {
            ProcessStartInfo i = new ProcessStartInfo();
            i.FileName = @"C:\long file path\run.cmd";
            i.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            i.UseShellExecute = true;
            i.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            using (Process p = Process.Start(i)) {
                error = "No process object was returned from Process.Start";
                if (p != null) {
                    p.WaitForExit();
                    if (p.ExitCode == 0) {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("OK");
                        Console.ResetColor();
                        return 0;
                    }
                    error = "Process exit code was " + p.ExitCode;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Win32Exception ex) {
            error = "(Win32Exception) " + ex.Message;
        }
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Whooops: " + error);
        Console.ResetColor();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The code starts a new process (as per your code sample) and reports the different ways in which it may fail to execute. You can compile the program from command line:

```
c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc test.cs
```

(assuming test.cs is in the current directory; it will create test.exe in the same directory as test.cs)

As expected, when "C:\long file path\run.cmd" does not exist, the program fails with:

```
Whooops: (Win32Exception) The system cannot find the file specified
```

Now let's create a directory "C:\long file path" and put a very simple run.cmd in there:

```
rem file run.cmd
echo I ran at %Time% > "%~dp0\run.out.txt"
```

However, at this point I was unable to reproduce your failure. Once the above run.cmd is in place, test.exe runs successfully (i.e. run.cmd is executed correctly - you can verify this by looking for a newly created file "C:\long file path\run.out.txt".

I ran test.exe on Vista x64 (my main dev machine), Windows XP SP3 x86 (virtual machine),  Windows Server 2008 x64 (virtual machine) and it works everywhere.

Could you try running the above code in your environment and report back whether it is failing for you? This way we will at least establish the same testing context (same .NET program will be trying to run the same batch file in the same location for you as it does for me).

Comment: Actually this is not the answer. But this gave me some lead to investigate and this was the most helpful to me. Since I don't have time to investigate it further before bounty expiration time, I selected this as the answer. I will post my findings when I have done that.

Answer (score 5):

It's curious, i reproduce the behavior, effectively, it doesn't execute as you stated, but modifying this, it worked:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process runScripts = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = @"run.cmd";
    // new
    runScripts.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\long file path";
    runScripts.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    runScripts.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    runScripts.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
    runScripts.Start();
```

Comment: Could show using Path.GetFileName and .GetDirectoryName to do just that for the user.

Answer (score 4):

I am unable to reproduce the behavior you're describing. The following code works for me.

```
string path = @"X:\Temp\long file path\run.cmd";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;

// Works with both true (default) and false.
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.Start();
```

**edit**

I am able to reproduce with the following code

```
  string path = @"X:\Temp\long file path";
  string file = "run.cmd";

  Process p = new Process();
  p.StartInfo.FileName = file;
  p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
  p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // only fails with false.
  p.Start();
  return;
```

This show (with Process Monitor) that ConsoleApplication.vshost.exe tries to find run.cmd in project\bin\Release, System32, System, Windows, System32\Wbem, and then further into some (I guess) path variables. It works, however, if I set UseShellExecute = true.

Comment: I agree that the problem is related with using UseShellExecute="false". I have a similar problem running a file at "..\Program Files\..." and it only fails when I set UseShellExecute="false".

Comment: Actually this is a documented feature. When using UseShellExecute=false you need to give the full path of the executable on the FileName see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I managed to actually run it by using following behavior.

```
    private string StartProcessAndGetResult(string executableFile, string arguments)
    //NOTE executable file should be passed as string with a full path
    //For example: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe
    //Without """ and @ signs
    {
        var result = String.Empty;
        var workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executableFile);


        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executableFile, arguments)
                                   {
                                       WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
                                       UseShellExecute = false,
                                       ErrorDialog = false,
                                       CreateNoWindow = true,
                                       RedirectStandardOutput = true
                                   };
        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        if (process != null)
        {
            using (var streamReader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The solution with @ or taking the string to quotes (""") did not wokred in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = @"""C:\long file path\run.cmd""";
```

Although I was sure it was done automatically for you by Process class. Are you sure you supplying the correct path?

Comment: I used this:
    runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + runScriptFile + "\"";
But still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have a hypothesis. 
Win32 has a limitation that strings used to descibe filenames cannot be longer then MAX_PATH (260 bytes) including terminating '\0'.

Maybe that problem has leaked into C#?

(The tests I've done indicates that, but I cannot confirm which bugs me.)

So, try to prefix your path with "\\?\". (backslash, backslash, questionmark, backslash)
I.e.

```
runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\?\C:\long file path\run.cmd";
```

For more details on MAX_PATH: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx

/Leif

Comment: I'm waiting for an update on MAX_PATH, 260 chars just doesn't cut it any more....

Comment: It's weird that you would say the 260 character limit has "leaked into C#". If you dig into the .NET libraries, you will find that everything that relates to the operating system is actually just a wrapper around a Win32 call (excluding Mono). For all practical purposes, Win32 isn't just one API for Windows; it's _THE_ API for Windows. .NET can't change that.

Comment: True, true.
I was trying to imply that the .NET wrappers could have automtically started to use the "\\?\"-trick when calling the OS with long paths.

Answer (score 1):

### (Update)

I think I found the problem from reverse engineering the Process.Start method a bit more.  I was along the right lines, **it fails without having a WorkingDirectory set.**

So in other words CreateProcess needs a valid workingdirectory, not .NET (it should really deduce it from the filename but obviously doesn't)

Here's the proof:

```
namespace SoTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcess([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpApplicationName, StringBuilder lpCommandLine, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandles, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpCurrentDirectory, STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\my test folder\my test.bat";

            StringBuilder cmdLine = new StringBuilder();
            cmdLine.Append(process.StartInfo.FileName);
            STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
            PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            // This fails
            //string workingDirectory = process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory;
            string workingDirectory = @"C:\my test folder\";

            CreateProcess(null, cmdLine, null, null, true, 0, IntPtr.Zero, workingDirectory, lpStartupInfo, lpProcessInformation);
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;

        public PROCESS_INFORMATION()
        {
            this.hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.hThread = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int nLength;
        public long lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class STARTUPINFO
    {
        public int cb;
        public IntPtr lpReserved;
        public IntPtr lpDesktop;
        public IntPtr lpTitle;
        public int dwX;
        public int dwY;
        public int dwXSize;
        public int dwYSize;
        public int dwXCountChars;
        public int dwYCountChars;
        public int dwFillAttribute;
        public int dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;

        public STARTUPINFO()
        {
            this.lpReserved = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.lpDesktop = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.lpTitle = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.lpReserved2 = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.hStdInput = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.hStdOutput = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.hStdError = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(this);
        }
    }       
}
```

I've removed SafeFileHandle from the original code as it wasn't needed for what we're doing. Also no start flags were set, but these are needed for a windowless version.

Comment: Are above listings internal implementations? From where did you find it?
So, for long file names we need to set WorkingDirectory while for short files we need not. Am I right? That sounds more like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes they're from looking at Reflector. Looking through, it trims the filename of all spaces so you need to set the working directory, which I assume the kernel32.dll (winapi CreateProcess call) prepends to the filename. I haven't tested it with a long path though

Comment: Trim() only removes leading and trailing spaces. It does not "trim the filename of all spaces".

Comment: +1 for Ch00k comment. Actually, the code you provided proves this SHOULD work WITHOUT using WorkingDirectory, as the FileName is wrapped in double quotes for you (if not wrapped already).

Comment: Yeh I was a bit hasty with the trim() conclusion, I'd forgotten it's only a left + right trim combined.

Comment: @Chris: could you try running my test program (along with the test run.cmd) in my answer and see if it fails for you?

Comment: @Chris: when I run your program with "string workingDirectory = null;", it still works for me :-) (running the exe from C:\temp)

Comment: I wonder if process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory defaults to "" or null? @Milan I'll try your code out tomorrow as the code above was tested on Vista 64bit.

Comment: @Milan I tested your code and it runs the long path correctly. Is a Win32Exception thrown if the file isn't found?

Comment: @Chris: Yes, Win32Exception is thrown when the cmd file can't be found. Not sure what failure @Thushan is experiencing though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process runScripts = new Process();
runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = @"""C:\long file path\run.cmd""";
runScripts.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
runScripts.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
runScripts.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
runScripts.Start();
```

I.e. use a quoted string for FileName when FileName has spaces.

Comment: I used this:

runScripts.StartInfo.FileName = "\"" + runScriptFile + "\"";

But still no luck.

Comment: Yep. I do a File.Exists and it passes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can fail for various reasons which are unrelated to the long/short path issue. You should add the exact exception description (including the call stack) to your question.